# Decomposition of a rational function

Tags: rational-functions

I want to decompose the rational function

$$
\cfrac{P(s)}{Q(s)}=\cfrac{\prod\limits_{i=1}^m (s+a_i)}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n (s+b_i)}
$$

where $a_i>0$ for every $i=1,\dots,m$, $b_i>0$ for every $i=1,\dots,n$ and $n>m$.

In other words, I'm looking for coefficients $x_j$, $j=1\dots,n$, such that

$$
\cfrac{P(s)}{Q(s)}=\cfrac{x_1}{s+b_1}+\dots+\cfrac{x_n}{s+b_n}\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad 
\sum_{j=1}^n x_j \prod_{\substack{i=1\\i\neq j}}^n (s+b_i) = \prod_{i=1}^m (s+a_i)
$$

Making some attempts with Mathematica for low values of $m$ and $n$ it seems that the $x_j$ are given by

$$
x_j=\cfrac{\prod\limits_{i=1}^m (a_i-b_j)}{\prod\limits_{\substack{i=1\\i\neq j}}^n (b_i-b_j)}
$$

So my questions are:

1) Can I say beforehand that there exist unique such $x_j$s?

2) How can I prove that $x_j$ has in general (as it seems) the form above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are real (or complex) polynomials?  This is known as "partial fractions", perhaps first seen by the typical student in elementary calculus courses.

(1) Suposing that your $P(s)/Q(s)$ in lowest terms, the necessary and sufficient condition that there exists $x_1,\dots,x_n$ such that
$$
\cfrac{P(s)}{Q(s)}=\cfrac{x_1}{s+b_1}+\dots+\cfrac{x_n}{s+b_n}
$$
Is: $m<n$ and no repeats among $b_1, b_2, \dots, b_n$.

(2) If such $x_j$ exist, they are unique.
Let's show $x_1$ is unique.  Suppose
$$
\cfrac{x_1}{s+b_1}+\dots+\cfrac{x_n}{s+b_n}
=\cfrac{u_1}{s+b_1}+\dots+\cfrac{u_n}{s+b_n}.
$$
Multiply by $s+b_1$, then take the limit as $s \to -b_1$.  Result:
$x_1=u_1$.  Uniqueness for the others is the same.

(3) They have the form you describe.
Let's prove it for $x_1$.  We have
$$
\cfrac{x_1}{s+b_1}+\dots+\cfrac{x_n}{s+b_n} = 
\cfrac{\prod\limits_{i=1}^m (s+a_i)}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n (s+b_i)}
$$
Multiply by $s+b_1$ to get
$$
x_1+ (s+b_1)\left(\cfrac{x_2}{s+b_2}+\dots+\cfrac{x_n}{s+b_n}\right) = 
\cfrac{\prod\limits_{i=1}^m (s+a_i)}{\prod\limits_{i=2}^n (s+b_i)}
$$
Take the limit as $s \to -b_1$ [remembering that $b_j \ne b_1$ for all other $b_j$ ]
$$
x_1 + 0 = \cfrac{\prod\limits_{i=1}^m (-b_1+a_i)}{\prod\limits_{i=2}^n (-b_1+b_i)}
$$
Does that match your claimed formula?

Comment: Yes, this sounds perfect! Thank you very much.There is only one typo in second-to-last equation, it's $\cfrac{x_2}{s+b_2}$. A part from that, in my problem I indeed have $m<n$ and $b_i\neq b_j$ for every $i\neq j$. Why exactly do these conditions imply the existence of $x_j$s? Should I simply set up the solving linear system and say that's solvable?

Comment: typo corrected, thanks